# Can not connect backend servers haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I am using following haproxy.cfg for connecting back end servers. but can not connect them.
haproxy server can ping both backend servers and client pc. http servers are running fine in both servers and dns server resolves ip address of the haproxy for both urls. no specific errors in haproxy.log. server os is centos 8 and selinux is disabled

```
global
    


    log /dev/log local2
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon


    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats


    ssl-default-bind-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM
    ssl-default-server-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM
frontend default
        bind *:80
        mode http
        timeout client 10s
        use_backend test1 if { hdr(host) -i test1.abc.com }
        use_backend test2 if { hdr(host) -i test2.abc.com }

backend test1
        mode http
        server test1 172.17.2.1:80 check
        timeout server 10s
        timeout connect 10s

backend test2
        mode http
        server test2 172.17.2.2:80 check
        timeout server 10s
        timeout connect 10s
```